# Failing to pass data from view to controller after submitting a form in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, controller

In my project, I have Cinema, Movie, and Screening Models. Now I want that a user would be able to order tickets for a screening of his choice, according to his chosen cinema. First, the user will select a cinema, then he will see the screenings that are available for the cinema he chose.

Using a `foreach` method I'm iterating over the screenings available in the chosen cinema and display them inside forms, so the user can click the "Order Now" button to submit the form for the specific screening he chose.

Here you can see my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CinemaProjectMVC.Models.Screening>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OrderForm";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Buy Tickets</h2>

<table id="screenings" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Tickets</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Order Now!</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            if (!Model.Any())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="empty-table" colspan="5">There are no screenings.</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        @foreach (var screening in Model)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Orders"))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
                <tr>

                    <td>@screening.Movie.Name</td>

                    <td>@screening.Date.ToString("d MMM yyyy, HH:mm")</td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => screening, new { @type = "number", Value = "1" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => screening)
                    </td>
                    <td id="@screening.Price">@screening.Price</td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="order-now-button">Order Now</button></td>
                </tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Id)
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, there is an issue with the line `@Html.HiddenFor(s => s.Id)`, probably because I'm using an `IEnumerable` as a Model. Without passing the Id in the form I can't pass it to another action.

I tried changing this line to `@Html.HiddenFor(s => screening.Id)` which compiles, but still i'm not getting the data I need in the "Save" action.

My Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(Screening screening)
{
    return RedirectToAction("", "");
}
```

Right now my action is empty, but through debugging I can see the "screening" variable is null after I submit the form.

This is the action that passes the data about screenings to the form in the OrderForm view:

```
public ActionResult AvailableScreenings(int id)
        {
            var screenings = _context.Screenings.Where(s => s.CinemaId == id).ToList();
            var cinemas = _context.Cinemas.ToList();
            var movies = _context.Movies.ToList();

            var viewModel = new ScreeningFormViewModel
            {
                Cinemas = cinemas,
                Movies = movies,
                Date = DateTime.Now
            };

            return View("OrderForm", screenings);
        }
```

And finally, I will add my Screening and ScreeningFormViewModel Models just in case -

Screening Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CinemaProjectMVC.Models
{
    public class Screening
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Cinema Cinema { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte CinemaId { get; set; }

        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte MovieId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Available Seats")]
        [ValidNumberOfSeats]
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid number")]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public Screening() { }

        public Screening(int id, Cinema cinema, Movie movie, byte cinemaId, byte movieId, DateTime date, int availableSeats, int price)
        {
            Id = id;
            Cinema = cinema;
            Movie = movie;
            CinemaId = cinemaId;
            MovieId = movieId;
            Date = date;
            AvailableSeats = availableSeats;
            Price = price;
        }
    }
}
```

ScreeningFormViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using CinemaProjectMVC.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CinemaProjectMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class ScreeningFormViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Cinema> Cinemas { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Cinemas")]
        public byte? CinemaId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Movies")]
        public byte? MovieId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Available Seats")]
        public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid number")]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return Id != 0 ? "Edit Screening" : "New Screening";
            }
        }

        public ScreeningFormViewModel()
        {
            Id = 0;
        }

        public ScreeningFormViewModel(Screening screening)
        {
            Id = screening.Id;
            CinemaId = screening.CinemaId;
            MovieId = screening.MovieId;
            Date = screening.Date;
            AvailableSeats = screening.AvailableSeats;
            Price = screening.Price;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where my problem is, maybe I'm not passing the right Model to the view, or maybe there are other issues in my form.

Comment: Seems like in the `AvailableScreenings()` action method the `View("OrderForm", screenings);` should be called with  the `viewModel` instead of  `screenings`.

Comment: What are you going to pass to the `OrderForm` view - instance of the `ScreeningFormViewModel` or `IEnumerable<CinemaProjectMVC.Models.Screening>`?

Comment: You are right, while trying different approaches I forgot to delete the viewModel from my code. The List of screenings is what I want to pass to the view, aka - `IEnumerable<CinemaProjectMVC.Models.Screening>`

Comment: What is this?  @Html.TextBoxFor(s => screening, new { @type = "number", Value = "1" })  are you going to put the whole object in text field?

Comment: No, this field is for the number of tickets the user wants to order, I don't have a Ticket property in my model (I figured out I don't need one) but yet I had to pass a lambda expression for the TextBoxFor, passing the whole object just worked for me so I left it as is. But I can see the problem now, how can I create this textbox without binding it to any properties from the Model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by modifying your view code as:

```
 @for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Orders"))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
            <tr>                    
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].Movie.Name</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m[i].Date.ToString("d MMM yyyy, HH:mm"))</td>

                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m[i].screening, new { @type = "number", Value = "1" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m =>m[i].screening)
                </td>
                <td>m=>m[i].Price</td>
                <td><button type="submit" class="order-now-button">Order Now</button></td>
            </tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        }
    }
```

Using this you can easily achieve what you actually wanted with the iterative form or we can say order based form.

Let me know if this answer is useful to you.